# Existe alguma forma de saber quantas vezes a função foi chamada?

Tags: php, funções

Gostaria de saber se no PHP existe alguma maneira de descobrir quantas vezes uma determinada função foi chamada.

Falo nativamente, visto que gostaria também de fazer essa verificação para funções nativas.

Exemplo:

```
 var_dump($_POST); 

 var_dump($_GET);

 get_function_called_number('var_dump'); // int(2)
```

Para satistazer apenas às exigências da pergunta, já demonstrarei na pergunta que sei como fazer isso pra para funções que eu criei.

Assim:

```
function call_me()
{
    static $count = 0;
    $count++;

    var_dump($count);
}

call_me(); // imprime int(1)

call_me(); // imprime int(2)
```

Porém gostaria de uma solução para saber sobre as funções nativas.

Comment: Eu nunca ví, mas iria ser de grande utilidade! :D

Comment: Na verdade, tudo que você quer é um Profiler (ver Xdebug + kcachegrind): http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler

Answer (score -1):

Há uma função nativa chamada [debug_backtrace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php)

Com o resultado retornado por essa função, poderá obter as informações que necessita.

De outro modo, teria que criar um controle personalizado. Tal controle é viável somente com uso de OOP.

Um exemplo de controle é identificar as chamadas dentro de um autoloader. No entanto, isso não controla as funções nativas. Para controlá-las teria que criar aliases e evitar chamá-las diretamente.

Answer (score -2):

**No PHP, não há uma maneira nativa de descobrir quantas vezes uma determinada função foi chamada**, incluindo funções nativas. No entanto, é possível usar uma técnica de envolvimento de função (**function wrapping**) para criar uma função personalizada que substitui a função nativa e adiciona a funcionalidade de contagem.

A técnica de envolvimento de função envolve a função nativa em outra função, que pode executar código antes ou depois da chamada à função original. Para contar o número de vezes que a função foi chamada, você pode definir uma variável estática dentro da função envolvente e incrementá-la a cada chamada à função original.

Por **exemplo**, você pode criar uma função personalizada **wrapped_var_dump** que envolve a função nativa **var_dump** e conta o número de vezes que ela é chamada:

```
function wrapped_var_dump()
{
    static $count = 0;
    $count++;

    $args = func_get_args();
    return call_user_func_array('var_dump', $args);
}
```

Nesta função, definimos uma variável estática **$count** para contar o número de vezes que a função é chamada. Em seguida, usamos **func_get_args** e **call_user_func_array** para chamar a função nativa **var_dump** com os argumentos passados para **wrapped_var_dump**.

Para usar essa função envolvente, basta chamá-la em vez da função nativa:

```
wrapped_var_dump($_POST);
wrapped_var_dump($_GET);
```

A cada chamada, a função **wrapped_var_dump** contará o número de vezes que a função original **var_dump** foi chamada e imprimirá o resultado. **Note que essa técnica pode ter um impacto negativo na performance do seu código**, pois envolver funções nativas pode tornar seu código mais lento. **Portanto, use com cuidado e somente quando for realmente necessário.**