# Existe alguma maneira de saber em qual local a função foi chamada?

Tags: php, funções

Se eu tenho um projeto enorme e percebo que, em algum lugar do código, uma função está sendo chamada, porém não sei qual lugar é, existe alguma maneira de se descobrir?

Exemplo:

```
#index.php

// nada aqui nesse script

#config.php

$config['database'] = config('database');

#view.php

$base_url = config('base_name');
```

Gostaria de algo como:

```
descubra_onde_a_funcao_foi_chamada('config');
```

E assim retornasse algo como:

```
    array(
      0 => array( 'file' => 'config.php', 'line' => 10),
      1 => array('file'  => 'view.php', 'line' => 15)
   );
```

Tem como fazer algo assim, em PHP, da mesma forma que demonstrei na função de exemplo?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94628/existe-alguma-forma-de-saber-quantas-vezes-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-foi-chamada possivel duplicada @wallace ?

Comment: Local onde a função foi chamada é diferente de quantas vezes foi chamada. Me ajuda aê, tião!

Comment: entendi, você acharia muito amplo reunir essa pergunta na outra ? uma função que verifica onde foi chamado e conta quantas vezes o mesmo foi executado ?

Comment: Sim, são assuntos diferentes. A não ser que a função faça as duas coisas, sem complicar o meio de campo.

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues, geralmente eu costumo agrupar perguntas, porém as vezes fica inviável (não gosto de respostas gigantes)

Answer (score 3):

A função [`debug_print_backtrace()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.debug-print-backtrace.php) exibe a pilha de chamadas até o ponto onde a função é executada.

Apesar de a documentação não mostrar, essa função recebe um parâmetro opcional com o valor da constante `DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS`, que oculta os parâmetros das funções chamadas.

```
<?php
debug_print_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS);
```

Exemplo de conteúdo exibido:

```
#0  c() called at [/tmp/include.php:10]
#1  b() called at [/tmp/include.php:6]
#2  a() called at [/tmp/include.php:17]
#3  include(/tmp/include.php) called at [/tmp/test.php:3]
```

Comment: Não existe uma função onde eu passo o nome da função como parâmetro e retorne só os locais de chamada dela?

Comment: Pelo visto, temos um probleminha: Essa função funciona quando chamada dentro de uma função, não é?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters algumas IDEs tem ferramentas que fazem esse processo. Por exemplo, o Netbeans, tem uma ferramente chamada "localizar usos" que faz exatamente isso

Comment: Olha, isso é bacana. Vou dar uma olhada. Pelo visto, para fazer pelo PHP é meio complexo